# Using more than one LINQ and receiving SystemNullReferenceException

Tags: android, linq, sqlite, xamarin

I use more than one LINQ in one function. The first LINQ works well but I have this error "SystemNullReferenceException" for the second LINQ, why?

```
var data = db.Table<LMLoginTable>();
var data1 = data.Where(x => x.DWFSeen == DW).Where(x => x.MWFSeen == MW).Where(x => x.YWFSeen == YW).FirstOrDefault();
if (data1.RFSeen == 0)
{
....

var data2 = data.Where(x => x.DWSSeen == DW).Where(x => x.MWSSeen == MW).Where(x => x.YWSSeen == YW).FirstOrDefault();
if (data2.RSSeen == 0)
{
.....
```

Comment: on which line do you get `SystemNullReferenceException`?

Comment: At first I saw this error on `if (data1.RFSeen == 0)` but after editing LINQ query, I saw this error on `if (data2.RSSeen == 0)`.

Comment: then obviously data2 is null. `data.Where(x => x.DWSSeen == DW).Where(x => x.MWSSeen == MW).Where(x => x.YWSSeen == YW).FirstOrDefault();` returns null